# Practical Parallel Efficiency % in Teradata

Tags: parallel-processing, teradata

Teradata is built for parallelism.
I believe that from the below query we can measure the Parallel Efficiency of user's query

```
SELECT 
USERNAME, 
NumOfActiveAMPs,
((sum(AMPCPUTime))/1024) / ((sum(MaxAmpCPUTime) * NumOfActiveAMPs)/1024) * 100 as Parallel_Efficiency,
count(1)
FROM dbc.qrylog 
WHERE MaxAmpCPUTime > 0 
group by 1,2
```

In a ideal situation, i believe PE can be 100%
But for various reasons, i see that most PE (rolled up) is usually less than 50%

What according to you is a good Parallel Efficiency % that we should try to achieve ?
I was told that trying to achieve a high PE (like 60% or more) is also not good for the state of the system, not sure of the reason though, is this true ? your thoughts ?

Thanks for sharing your thoughts !

Answer (score 0):

Parallel Efficiency for a given query can be calculated as `AMPCPUTime / (MaxAMPCPUTime * (HASHAMP () + 1))`. Where `(MaxAMPCPUTime * (HASHAMP () + 1))` is the `ImpactCPU` measure, representing the highest CPU consumed by a participating AMP in the query multiplied by the number of AMPs in the configuration. You may find individual workloads are all over the board on their parallel efficiency.

> I some times wonder if PE for an individual query would be more accurate if you replace the number of nodes in the system with the number of AMPs used by the query. This metric is available in DBQL and may help balance queries that are using PI or USI access paths that are not all AMP operations.

Parallel efficiency for your overall system can be obtained using ResUsage metrics by dividing the average node utilization by the maximum node utilization. This helps you understand how evenly the system is processing a given workload but does not consider how "heavy" that workload might be. Here you are looking to see the overall efficiency to be greater than 60%, the closer to 100% the better the nodes are working together.

I know your inquiry was about individual queries, but I thought sharing details about the PE of your environment would be beneficial as well.